# Silverlight 4: Chart Control

Tags: silverlight, charts, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

Is there a **free** chart control for silverlight 4 except for toolkit?

Comment: Just out of interest, why are you excluding SL Toolkit?

Comment: because I already tried it. I'm looking for something that's why. thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a number of charting components for Silverlight, some of the most popular free ones are the following:

- [Visiblox](http://www.visiblox.com/) - free version supports basic chart types, zooming, trackball and some other behaviours, comes with a watermark though. The [documentation](http://www.visiblox.com/docs) is decent. Good choice if you need performant charts or are planning on building on top of them. [See examples using this component](http://www.visiblox.com/examples).
- [AmCharts QuickCharts](http://wpf.amcharts.com/quick) - a set of basic charts. [Documentation](http://wpf.amcharts.com/quicksldocs/) is pretty basic. Good choice if you need the most basic charts. [See examples using this component](http://wpf.amcharts.com/quick).
- [Visifire](http://www.visifire.com) - lots of chart types
  supported and they have a nice chart
  designer. [Documentation](http://www.visifire.com/visifire_charts_documentation.php) is also
  decent. Good choice for a wide range
  of charting applications. [See
  examples using this component](http://www.visifire.com/silverlight_charts_gallery.php). **Update:** since I've written this, Visifire have went to having only trial. Thus probably worth being a bit vary of them in terms of licensing.

***Full Disclosure:*** I have been heavily involved in development of Visiblox, hence I know that library in much more detail than the others.

Answer (score 3):

A free version of [Visiblox Charts](http://www.visiblox.com) is available for download for Silverlight 4 and WPF.

Answer (score 0):

I find Visifire open source chart controls very good:

http://visifire.codeplex.com/

Comment: Visifire have since gone from being open source to being closed source and only offering a trial: http://www.visifire.com/blog/2011/02/08/license-changes/. V3 is left as open source, however there's no source available for v4 (neither a free version).

Answer (score 0):

Check out amCharts [Quick Charts](http://wpf.amcharts.com/quick) which are free and open-source and [Stock Chart](http://wpf.amcharts.com/stock) which is free with as long as you don't mind a small link back in the corner